# Using "..." and "replicate"

Tags: r, ellipsis, replicate, sapply

In the documentation of `sapply` and `replicate` there is a warning regarding using `...`

Now, I can accept it as such, but would like to understand what is behind it. So I've created this little contrived example:

```
innerfunction<-function(x, extrapar1=0, extrapar2=extrapar1)
{
    cat("x:", x, ", xp1:", extrapar1, ", xp2:", extrapar2, "\n")
}

middlefunction<-function(x,...)
{
    innerfunction(x,...)
}

outerfunction<-function(x, ...)
{
    cat("Run middle function:\n")
    replicate(2, middlefunction(x,...))
    cat("Run inner function:\n")
    replicate(2, innerfunction(x,...))
}

outerfunction(1,2,3)
outerfunction(1,extrapar1=2,3)
outerfunction(1,extrapar1=2,extrapar2=3)
```

Perhaps I've done something obvious horribly wrong, but I find the result of this rather upsetting. So can anyone explain to me why, in all of the above calls to `outerfunction`, I get this output:

```
Run middle function:
x: 1 , xp1: 0 , xp2: 0 
x: 1 , xp1: 0 , xp2: 0 
Run inner function:
x: 1 , xp1: 0 , xp2: 0 
x: 1 , xp1: 0 , xp2: 0
```

Like I said: the docs seem to warn for this, but I do not see why this is so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`?replicate`, in the Examples section, tells us explicitly that what you are trying to do does not and will not work. In the `Note` section of `?replicate` we have:

```
     If ‘expr’ is a function call, be aware of assumptions about where
     it is evaluated, and in particular what ‘...’ might refer to.  You
     can pass additional named arguments to a function call as
     additional named arguments to ‘replicate’: see ‘Examples’.
```

And if we look at Examples, we see:

```
 ## use of replicate() with parameters:
 foo <- function(x=1, y=2) c(x,y)
 # does not work: bar <- function(n, ...) replicate(n, foo(...))
 bar <- function(n, x) replicate(n, foo(x=x))
 bar(5, x=3)
```

My reading of the docs is that they do far more than warn you about using `...` in `replicate()` calls; they explicitly document that it does not work. Much of the discussion in that help file relates to the `...` *argument* of the other functions, not necessarily to `replicate()`.

Comment: Note that in the example, event the "correct" way doesn't work properly - it is replicated `x` times (3) rather than `n` times (5).

Comment: @James - not on my system. I get a 2*5 matrix for `bar(5, x = 3)`

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Had a typo when transcribing the examples.

Comment: @Gavin: The quote from `?replicate` is the warning I mentioned in my question. What I would like to know is what this warning means? 'where it is evaluated' and 'what ... might refer to' are somewhat cryptic to me. So, again: I accept that it doesn't work, but _why_ doesn't it work? This might greatly help my/others' understanding of argument passing/parsing in R.

Comment: @Nick sorry for late reply; To my mind, the reason this doesn't work is that you are *not* calling the function in `expr`, you are just evaluating `expr`. Because you are not calling it, there is no passing of arguments from the outer call `...` to the `expr`. This is a subtle difference but is very important; it is as if you called `middlefunction(...)` exactly like that in the global environment (you can't because R doesn't allow you to use `...` interactively like that) where `...` doesn't refer to anything.

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the code for `replicate`:

```
> replicate
function (n, expr, simplify = TRUE) 
sapply(integer(n), eval.parent(substitute(function(...) expr)), 
    simplify = simplify)
<environment: namespace:base>
```

You see that the function is evaluated in the parent frame, where the `...` from your calling function no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a way to do this:

```
# Simple function:
ff <- function(a,b) print(a+b)

# This will NOT work:
testf <- function(...) {
  replicate(expr = ff(...), n = 5)
}
testf(45,56) # argument "b" is missing, with no default

# This will:
testf <- function(...) {
  args <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  replicate(expr = do.call(ff, args), n = 5)
}
testf(45,56) # 101
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do that:

```
g <- function(x, y) x + y

f <- function(a = 1, ...) {
    arg_list <- list(...)
    replicate(n = 3, expr = do.call(g, args = arg_list))
}

f(x = 1, y = 2)
```