# Using mapply inside a function(...)

Tags: r, mapply

I'm trying to generate several series of random numbers, each series with a different set of parameters. Then I want to replicate all of that. I want to have a function to do this, and it seems like it should be a 1-liner with something like `rnorm()` to generate the numbers, `mapply()` to generate those numbers for several parameter sets, and `replicate()` to repeat the whole process.

To achieve that, I wrote a function whose `...` arguments I want to correspond to the `...` in `mapply`, but it appears that `...` is being ignored by `mapply`. I have some examples that should clarify my desired output, as well as the problem:

```
 # Some values to be passed to the ... of mapply
 mus <- c(-30, 0, 30)
 sds <- c(0.1, 1, 10)

 # =================================
 # = What I want, if it would work =
 # =================================
 f <- function(n=3, ...){
    replicate(2, mapply(rnorm, MoreArgs=list(n=n), ...))
 }
 f(mean=mus, sd=sds) # Doesn't work :(

>, , 1
>
>           [,1]
>[1,] -0.4901243
>[2,]  0.8268027
>[3,] -0.4829781
>
>, , 2
>
>            [,1]
>[1,] -0.02025903
>[2,] -1.57011537
>[3,]  0.49234503


# ==========================================================
# = What I can currently get to work, but not style I want =
# ==========================================================
# I can't understand why f.inside is needed!
f2 <- function(n=3, ...){
    f.inside <- function() mapply(rand.gen, MoreArgs=list(n=n), ...)
    replicate(2, f.inside())
}
f2(mean=mus, sd=sds) # Desired output

>, , 1
>
>          [,1]        [,2]      [,3]
>[1,] -29.83762 -0.06138165  9.956601
>[2,] -30.04880  1.39123405 33.036675
>[3,] -29.94070 -1.15741513 19.337497
>[4,] -29.92360  0.74300731 38.741367
>[5,] -29.81723  0.84565813 22.261605
>
>, , 2
>
>          [,1]       [,2]     [,3]
>[1,] -30.01407 -0.5198845 20.85942
>[2,] -29.77586 -0.1705062 22.06274
>[3,] -29.96901 -0.4412471 21.42849
>[4,] -30.04079  0.4230790 28.35480
>[5,] -30.04794  0.3000821 50.09012
```

I'm guessing I need to wrap the `...` in something; I've haphazardly tried things like `alist()`, `list()`, `bquote()`, `expression()`, `as.call()` and several other failed approaches.

<s>**1) Why does `mapply` in `f()` appear to completely ignore the `...`?**</s>
**EDIT**: This was an ancillary question, to which the answer is "dots don't work with replicate". OK, on to the core question...

```
# =====================================
# = OK, Function for Refined Question =
# =====================================
f.edit <- function(n=3, ...){
    l <- list(...)
    replicate(2,mapply(rnorm, MoreArgs=list(n=n), l))
}
f.edit(mean=mus, sd=sds) # Doesn't work :(
```

**2) How do I split the elements of an object into length(object) elements, and pass those as separate items to `mapply`'s `...`?**

I need to get better at my ellipses. I'm really stumped on this one.

Comment: Better solution is to use the fact that `rnorm` is already vectorized over its `mean` and `sd` arguments. For example, `f<-function(n,reps,mean,sd) {m<-length(mean);aperm(array(rnorm(n*m*reps,mean,sd),c(m,n,reps)),c(2,1,3))}`

Comment: @A.Webb Nice, good point; unfortunately, I'm doing this in the style of `arima.sim`; i.e., `rnorm` can be any number-generating function that has `n` as an argument. But you make a good point.

Comment: Regarding the `f.edit` edit, try instead `function(n=3, ...){dots<-list(...);replicate(2, do.call(mapply,c(list(FUN=rnorm),dots,list(MoreArgs=list(n=n)))))}`

Comment: @A.Webb That's it! OK, I had tried something along the lines of `do.call`, but I botched it; I'm still trying to wrap my head around why that exact structure of `list()` and `c()` is needed, but asfaik, it is necessary. Nice, thank you.

Comment: @nongkrong Your solution works, but I am still trying to understand it. I'd never used the ``` notation before, so thanks for introducing me to that, as well as `as.call`, which I'm also not familiar with. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @rbatt it is similar to the `do.call` solution, except you construct the call yourself.  The backticks are just a way to name/call things, for example try `\`one and two\` <- 3; \`one and two\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fashion you are attempting in `f.edit`...

- You can construct the argument list and perform a `do.call` with `mapply`

  ```
  function(n=3, ...){
    dots<-list(...);
    replicate(2,do.call(mapply,c(list(FUN=rnorm),dots,list(MoreArgs=list(n=n)))))
  }
  ```
- Or, extract the arguments and call directly

  ```
  function(n=3, ...){
    dots<-list(...);
    replicate(2,mapply(rnorm,dots$mean,dots$sd,MoreArgs=list(n=n)))
  }
  ```

In either case you force evaluation of `...` in the correct environment, as is also done in your `f2` and [MrFlick's alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31842965/1756702).

The problem with `f.edit` as written is that `rnorm` is being called as `rnorm(n,list(means=mus,sd=sds))` rather than `rnorm(n,means=mu,sd=sds)`.

---

However, in this case you might consider using the fact that `rnorm` is already vectorized over its mean and sd arguments

```
function(n,reps,mean,sd) {
  m<-length(mean);
  aperm(array(rnorm(n*m*reps,mean,sd),c(m,n,reps)),c(2,1,3))
}
```

Comment: so in `f.edit`, there's no way of doing something to `l` to allow it to work? I'm just trying to wrap my head around this. I know I'm only passing 1 argument, instead of several ... but can I split that 1 into several? I guess that's what you're doing with do.call.

Comment: @rbatt See if edits above clear up what's going on in `f.edit`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not allowed to use `...` with `replicate` as already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704536/and-replicate).

I already think you found the most readable alternative with the helper function `f.inside()` to grab the `...` terms.

Another options is to avoid `replicate` and use `lapply` (with index values that you ultimately ignore)

```
f3 <- function(n=3, ...){
    lapply(1:2, function(i, ...) mapply(rnorm, MoreArgs=list(n=n), ...), ...)
}
f3(mean=mus, sd=sds)
```